# Populate array with null values

Tags: java, arrays, collections

Maybe that's simple question.
But, I wonder to know why we can't populate array or collection with null values?
Please look such simple example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
   map.put("first",null);
   map.put("first1",new BigDecimal(1.5));
   map.put("first2",new BigDecimal(2.5));
   map.put("first3",new BigDecimal(3.5));


   String[]array1 = new String[map.values().size()];
   Object[]array2 = new Object[map.values().size()];

   int counter = 0;

   for(Map.Entry<String,Object> entry: map.entrySet()){

       String header = entry.getKey();
       Object value = entry.getValue();

       array1[counter] = header;
       array2[counter] = value;

       counter++;

   }
}
```

I would be glad to listen your purposes.

Comment: What's the issue with that code?

Comment: A `Map` has a `size` method so no need for `map.values().size()` just use `map.size()`.

Comment: *we can't populate array or collection with null* That's not true...

Comment: Some collections allow null values, some don't.

Comment: array2 - doesn't populates with null values.

Comment: 1 remark should be done:                                   String[]array1 = new String[map.keySet().size()];
Object[]array2 = new Object[map.values().size()];

Comment: Could you please elaborate what do you expect in the result ?

Comment: what are `array2`'s values after you populate it?

Comment: There is only one `null` value in your map. I would expect `array2` to have one `null` value at index 0 and three BigDecimal values at indices 1, 2, and 3. Is that not what you are seeing?

Comment: I suggest changing the accepted answer, since few people have your original problem of not seeing the nulls in the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code under your for-loop and you'll see that not only are the sizes equal to that of the map, the elements are the same too.

```
System.out.println("counter = " + counter);
System.out.println("array1.length = " + array1.length);
for(int i=0; i<array1.length; i++) {
   System.out.printf("- array1[%d] = %s\n", i, array1[i]);
}
System.out.println("array2.length = " + array2.length);
for(int i=0; i<array2.length; i++) {
   System.out.printf("- array2[%d] = %s\n", i, array2[i]);
}
```

The order will probably not be the same order you entered the values in but that's due to the nature of the HashMap. My output was:

```
counter = 4
array1.length = 4
- array1[0] = first3
- array1[1] = first2
- array1[2] = first
- array1[3] = first1
array2.length = 4
- array2[0] = 3.5
- array2[1] = 2.5
- array2[2] = null
- array2[3] = 1.5
```

Comment: The interesting thing is, that in IDE (Debuger) we can't see elements with null values.

Comment: Maybe some settings have to be changed in the debugger then; as you can see above the values are certainly there. Maybe there's a "don't show null values" switch somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

An object array *is* populated with `null` values when it's instantiated. Collections on the other hand are empty at the beginning, so there' nothing that can be "populated" in the first place - well, you could fill them with `null` values if you wanted, but what would be the point of that? only add elements *as needed* to a `Collection`, it makes no sense to fill it with `null` values (and not all collections will allow it, it depends on the type).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Arrays.fill`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d,%20java.lang.Object%29) to fill an array with values, e.g.:

```
String[] arr = new String[5]; 
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
Arrays.fill(arr,"initial value");
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
Arrays.fill(arr,null);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
```

outputs:

```
[null, null, null, null, null]
[initial value, initial value, initial value, initial value, initial value]
[null, null, null, null, null]
```

Answer (score 0):

When using generics, I think the best practice is to specify something more specific than Object, in order to be more typesafe.  So you may want to update the HashMap to:

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> map = new HashMap<Sting, BigDecimal>();
```

Then you can create null BigDecimal objects to populate your map.

Comment: In my case I should use Object, bacause I need different types to store in map. Like: Date, Integer, String, BigDecimal

Comment: Consider creating a common interface for your types since I think this will make better object oriented code.